# Survminer - include subset of variables in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival, survminer

Let's say I want to plot the survival curves using a model of the lung data, that controls for sex and a median split of the age variable (I could also control linearly for age and that would make my problem even worse).

I would like to make a plot of this model only showing the stratification between the levels of the sex factor. If I do what seems to be the standard, however, I get 4 instead of two survival curves.

```
library(survival)
library(survminor)
reg_lung <- lung %>% mutate(age_cat = ifelse(age > 63, "old", "young"))
lung_fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ age_cat + sex, data = reg_lung)
ggsurvplot(lung_fit, data = reg_lung)
```

[resulting survival plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr85M.png)

That is to say, I would like to the difference sex makes while holding the influence of age fixed (either as factor old/young or linearly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fit your model with `coxph` and define sex as strata:

```r
lung_fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age_cat + strata(sex), data = reg_lung)
ggsurvplot(survfit(lung_fit), data = reg_lung)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome I suspected it was a simple thing that I just could not figure out. Thanks!